# The Security to the Party [Part 2]

Tags: password

A party is being held at a local mansion. The host is very rich and his success is because of one thing ~ his famous recipe for Spaghetti!

The only guests that may attend are people who correctly reply to the guard at the door.

Here's where you come in. You and a friend are trying to steal this recipe. You sneak by and listen to the passwords.

The first guest arrives. The security says "5", and the guest replies "5".

The second guest arrives. The security says "6", the guest replies "6".

Your friend walks up to the door and the security says "7" arrives. He replies with "7", and is told to leave.

Another guest arrives, you seem to get the same pattern, security says "1" and he says "**2**" to get in.

Another guest arrives, you seem to get the same pattern, security says "4" and he says "4" to get in.

You now walk up to security and get "3", what is the correct response?

Part 1 was created by warspyking and is found here:  [The Security to the Party](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/3981/the-security-to-the-party)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> The answer corresponds to the number of segments used on creating the number on a 7 segment display. Because 3 has 5 segments on a 7 segment display, the answer is 5

Comment: security says "7" arrives. He replies with "7", the answer for 7 should be 3

Comment: @Mew Why does 7 need 7 segments?

Comment: @miracle173: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven-segment_display

Comment: @ThePopMachine ??? The wiki article says that 7 uses 3 of the segments or do you read it in a different way?

Comment: @miracle173:   I misread.   I thought someone was asking why it should be 3 instead of 2.

Comment: @miracle173 It doesn't, that person is denied access.