# The Security to the Party [Part 3]

Tags: pattern, password

A party is being held at a local mansion. The host is very rich and his success is because of one thing — his famous recipe for Spaghetti!

The only guests that may attend are people who correctly reply to the guard at the door.

Here's where you come in. You and a friend are trying to steal this recipe. You sneak by and listen to the passwords.

The first guest arrives. The security says "5", and the guest replies "0".

The second guest arrives. The security says "6", the guest replies "1".

The third guest arrives. The security says "3", the guest replies "0".

Your friend thinks he's got it all figured out so he walks up to the door and the security says "2". He replied "1", and is chased by dogs for stating an incorrect password.

Another guest arrives, you seem to get the same pattern, security says "1" and he says "0" to get in.

You now walk up to security and get "7", what is the correct response?

hint 1:

> Another guest arrives, you seem to get the same pattern, security says "8" and he says "2" to get in.

hint 2:

> Another guest arrives, you seem to get the same pattern, security says "0" and he says "1" to get in.

No computations are needed for this problem so please don't answer using complex equations, it's just simple logic.

Thanks for the ideas, credits to:

Part 1 was created by warspyking and is found here: [The Security to the Party](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/3981/the-security-to-the-party)

Part 2 in Mew's version [The Security to the Party [Part 2]](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/3991/the-security-to-the-party-part-2)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> Number of circles in the figure ????

It seems ridiculous, but

> 5,3,1 have got no full circles, 6 has got 1, 8 has 2

Then for 7 the reply should be

> 0

Comment: yup quite correct it is actually the number of closed figures or whatever you call it in each number, i got the idea from this post [link](https://www.facebook.com/oOoDanthemanoOo/posts/572469709484506)

Comment: :P, I got this from my 5 year old niece....;)

Comment: i think it would be clearer that its not just the circles if i added number '4' in the example, but i assumed that some people might get confused because other format of '4' has an opening in it, haha anyway thumbs up for you and your niece