# The Security to the Party [Part 4]

Tags: pattern, password

A party is being held at a local mansion. The host is very rich and his success is because of one thing — his famous recipe for Spaghetti!

The only guests that may attend are people who correctly reply to the guard at the door.

Here's where you come in. You and a friend are trying to steal this recipe. You sneak by and listen to the passwords.

The first guest arrives. The security says "5", and the guest replies "2".

The second guest arrives. The security says "6", the guest replies "2".

The third guest arrives. The security says "3", the guest replies "2".

Your friend thinks he's got it all figured out so he walks up to the door and the security says "2". He replied "2", and is tarred and feathered and sent away in shame.

Another guest arrives, security says "0" and he says "0" to get in.

You walk up and get a "4" from security. What is your response?

Thanks for the ideas, credits to:

Part 1 was created by warspyking and is found here: [The Security to the Party](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/3981/the-security-to-the-party)

Part 2 in Mew's version [The Security to the Party [Part 2]](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/3991/the-security-to-the-party-part-2)

Part 3 in Kelvin Barsana's version [The Security to the Party [Part 3]](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/3997/the-security-to-the-party-part-3)

Comment: why is it part 4, its a variation, why do you call it "part"?

Comment: @skv, hey - that's a good riddle. I'll post it as a separate question.

Comment: probably because the other are also named part 2, part 3, et cetera

Comment: @skv, ;). just because the rest of them did.

Comment: woohoow, one answer correct!

Comment: @Mathias711, +1

Comment: @skv, I'm to young on the site to add a tag, but I figured this might take a tag of it's own (it's not just [tag:pattern]). **Edit**: just got enough points :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Answer:

> Respond $1$.

Explanation:

> Put x into binary. The number of 1s in the result is the answer.
>  Here is a key for the given numbers:
>  $$\begin{align}5&=101 &\rightarrow 2 \\ 6&=110 &\rightarrow 2 \\ 3&=11 &\rightarrow 2 \\ 2&=10 &\rightarrow 1 \\ 0&=0 &\rightarrow 0 \\ 4&=100 &\rightarrow 1\end{align}$$

Answer (score 7):

> Number of 1's in the binary code of the decimal number being called.....

So for 4 the response should be

> 1