# Decode the message enciphered in these symbols: ◳◰ ◓◨ ◨◧◕ ◎◌ ◱◯◱◯ ◍◌○ ◉◉ ◇◔◓◕ ◐►◓◒ ◒◑ ◈◑ ◆◆◓ ◉◉◉

Tags: cipher, symbols

◳◰ ◓◨ ◨◧◕ ◎◌ ◱◯◱◯ ◍◌○ ◉◉ ◇◔◓◕ ◐►◓◒ ◒◑ ◈◑ ◆◆◓ ◉◉◉

---

Administrative details (not part of the puzzle):

- The answer is a clue to [The Security to the Party [12] (now with party soundtrack!)](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/4057/the-security-to-the-party-12-now-with-party-soundtrack)
- For the benefit of anyone without a Unicode-capable browser, the puzzle should look like this (image of the puzzle text): 
  [image: ◳◰ ◓◨ ◨◧◕ ◎◌ ◱◯◱◯ ◍◌○ ◉◉ ◇◔◓◕ ◐►◓◒ ◒◑ ◈◑ ◆◆◓ ◉◉◉]
- The answer is written text in the English language. The puzzle is: **"◳◰ ◓◨ ◨◧◕ ◎◌ ◱◯◱◯ ◍◌○ ◉◉ ◇◔◓◕ ◐►◓◒ ◒◑ ◈◑ ◆◆◓ ◉◉◉" is the cyphertext. What is the plaintext?**
- This type of puzzle is called a [Cryptogram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptogram). The Google search "[How to solve a cryptogram](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?q=%22how%20to%20solve%20a%20cryptogram%22)" leads to all kinds of useful resources, hints and tips.
- The puzzle is *not* case-sensitive (see question below).
- The plaintext does not contain any slang or acronyms (see question below).
- Chat about this question is here: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18659/discussion-on-question-by-a-e------------- (contains spoilers!)
- There are no proper nouns (names) in the plaintext. (question from chat)
- The plaintext does not contain roman numerals. (question from chat)
- There is no punctuation in the plaintext. (question from chat)

---

Thank you @Kevin for providing a list of names of the symbols, for anyone who's having trouble with fonts (also good from an accessibility point of view, I guess). So everyone's on a level playing field, I've copied it below:

```
WHITE SQUARE WITH UPPER RIGHT QUADRANT
WHITE SQUARE WITH UPPER LEFT QUADRANT
SPACE
CIRCLE WITH UPPER HALF BLACK
SQUARE WITH RIGHT HALF BLACK
SPACE
SQUARE WITH RIGHT HALF BLACK
SQUARE WITH LEFT HALF BLACK
CIRCLE WITH ALL BUT UPPER LEFT QUADRANT BLACK
SPACE
BULLSEYE
DOTTED CIRCLE
SPACE
WHITE SQUARE WITH LOWER LEFT QUADRANT
LARGE CIRCLE
WHITE SQUARE WITH LOWER LEFT QUADRANT
LARGE CIRCLE
SPACE
CIRCLE WITH VERTICAL FILL
DOTTED CIRCLE
WHITE CIRCLE
SPACE
FISHEYE
FISHEYE
SPACE
WHITE DIAMOND
CIRCLE WITH UPPER RIGHT QUADRANT BLACK
CIRCLE WITH UPPER HALF BLACK
CIRCLE WITH ALL BUT UPPER LEFT QUADRANT BLACK
SPACE
CIRCLE WITH LEFT HALF BLACK
BLACK RIGHT-POINTING POINTER
CIRCLE WITH UPPER HALF BLACK
CIRCLE WITH LOWER HALF BLACK
SPACE
CIRCLE WITH LOWER HALF BLACK
CIRCLE WITH RIGHT HALF BLACK
SPACE
WHITE DIAMOND CONTAINING BLACK SMALL DIAMOND
CIRCLE WITH RIGHT HALF BLACK
SPACE
BLACK DIAMOND
BLACK DIAMOND
CIRCLE WITH UPPER HALF BLACK
SPACE
FISHEYE
FISHEYE
FISHEYE
```

Comment: Nice. The four square symbols renders in my browser as empty squares. Don't know why...

Comment: I'm using chrome too. Odd...

Comment: I think that you will need to add something more to explain the challenge, otherwise some people might close-vote as "unclear what you're asking".

Comment: Curiously, all the symbols render correct in my URL, but not in the page. So this might be something about the system fonts... Anyway, I have the picture.

Comment: Also, the explanation is kind of lax.

Comment: @QuyNguyen2013: What kind of clarification do you think would improve it? I can add more explanation.

Comment: What type of cipher is this?

Comment: @QuyNguyen2013, working that out is part of the puzzle.

Comment: This is probably like webdings or something. Check it out on notepad fonts.

Comment: @warspyking On notepad it renders exactly as the image using something like arial or times new roman...

Comment: A little additional help for people having font problems: [here](http://pastebin.com/WAhM3TCd) is a list of each character's name.

Comment: @Kevin link blocked at work :(

Comment: I'll add Kevin's text to the question so everyone can see it.

Comment: Tried writing `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ 0123456789` on Webdings, Wingdings, Wingdings 2 and Wingdings 3, and nope, just one or two of the symbols matched anything more by luck than anything else. However these symbols are present in the Segoe font family.

Comment: Two "words" made up only by the symbol "◉" (fisheye). That symbol never occurs with any other symbol in the same word. So, this may be some sort of separator. Or might be numbers: 2 and 3.

Comment: So I took each of these characters' hex value and converted them to decimal. And I'm nowhere. http://imgur.com/lWEDhW2

Comment: I'm wondering why no word has more than 4 letters. It is hard to write any useful english text without words with more than 4 letters.

Comment: I wonder if most of the difficulty of this puzzle would be negated if it wasn't written in Unicode...

Comment: Is the music tracks from the party something to do about the message or to the procedure used for decoding it?

Comment: Hi @Victor! No: the answer to this puzzle is a clue for the party puzzle, but the party puzzle does *not* provide you with any clues for this one or anything you need to solve this one. It's a one-way relationship. You can safely ignore the music tracks for now.

Comment: @Victor, good idea though! :)

Comment: @Victor re your fisheye, the pattern becomes 16/2/15/3 - or 18/18

Comment: I pasted the symbols into MS Word. Most of them come out in a font called MS Mincho, but a few in Times New Roman. They all seem to be pretty close together in Word's list of symbols. Can they all be translated backwards to land on letters of the alphabet?

Comment: This is so-o-o confusing! May be you can just leave the photo and conditions of the puzzle + your question about it (and remove all other historical stuff)?

Comment: Can you please tell if all the non-space characters fall in the range a-zA-Z? Or at least in the 32-126 code-point (ANSI) ranges?

Comment: @Victor: the answer is English text using the normal character range.

Comment: By the way folks, I've added to the question some links about how to solve this general class of puzzle.

Comment: I feel like the double fish eye symbol is the separator. The it makes an even 16 symbols. I dont think simple substitution works here because the words are too small. it may be a block cipher since 16 is a square number.

Comment: @stackErr but the second set is 15, not 16

Comment: @Raystafarian Theres three fisheyes at the end. I am considering one to be in the ciphertext and the double fisheye as the separator. I could be totally wrong as well :/

Comment: Surely "◱◯◱◯" is an interesting word. How many english words have the "xyxy" structure?

Comment: There also 21 different symbols. Assuming that these are two sentences, and that punctuation is included. I am guessing that there are atleast 18~19 letters out of the alphabet used. Which is a lot for such a small sentence.

Comment: My frequency analysis on the cipher if anyone needs it: http://i.imgur.com/DUabfcF.png

and theres 12 spaces

Comment: @AE Is it case-sensitive? I.E. Do upper and lower case letters encode different symbols?

Comment: @Victor: it's not case-sensitive. I'll add that info to the question. Great teamwork by the way guys, some very interesting analysis going on here!

Comment: I think I have a good idea of what kind of cipher it is! A variation of a http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigpen_cipher cipher. The square is encoded 12 different ways. The circle 12 different ways. and the triangle 2 different ways. Now I just need to allocate the letters to each symbol.

Comment: @AE Are there any concatenations? Or slang? Or acronyms?

Comment: My thoughts, in a different direction, was that the first 16 letters make 2 words (fisheye) and the next 15 letters makes 3 words (fisheye)

Comment: Most symbols are circles, diamonds and squares. The only exception is "►" (triangle pointing to right). Maybe this is important, specially if this is indeed a Pigpen.

Comment: @Raystafarian you work in that direction while I try the pigpen method. Lets see where we get

Comment: Not working with the symbols anymore, it should look like this - "zyabbwcvdefefudtxxsracqpajjhmhggaxxx"

Comment: Are they musical notes? Where the symbols can be read as a number, separated by spaces. And the number is converted to an alphabet. Lol

Comment: @Raystafarian I too, were working with `ab cd def gh ijij khl mm nocf pqcr rs ts uuc mmm`. I suspect that the given text is written right-to-left too. (i.e. backwards)

Comment: @stackErr: correction: The plaintext does not contain any  slang or acronyms.

Comment: **Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18659/discussion-on-question-by-a-e-------------).**

Comment: Can we assume that the spaces are at the correct position?

Comment: @ProgramFOX: The cyphertext definitely does not contain any errors, I've proofed it very carefully. The sequence of characters in the cyphertext is what I intended it to be.

Comment: (I haven't proof-read the list of character names provided by Kevin - I'm just assuming it matches).

Comment: @AE Okay, thanks! I did not mean to say that there are any errors, just wanted to know. If the spaces are at the right positions, it's easier to solve anyway ;)

Comment: @ProgramFOX: If you're asking "do the spaces in the ciphertext correspond to spaces in the same position in the plaintext", then I'm afraid I can't tell you that without giving you information about the cipher, which would be a Clue. (And that's ok, you're welcome to ask).

Comment: @AE Yes, that's what I wanted to ask. Thanks for your new comment!

Comment: My browser replaces SPACE with SPAAAaaace :P

Answer (score 42, accepted):

> MAGICSIBLINGS 
>  It's morse code, with every circular symbol representing a dot and every other symbol representing a dash. The content of the symbols is a red herring.

Comment: CORRECT! Well done!

Comment: I cannot begin to imagine the thought processes that led user 5352 to the right solution. It sends shivers down my spine!

Comment: @augustin you might like the [mutilated chessboard problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutilated_chessboard_problem).  It's a similar "projection" problem, where the answer comes about pretty quickly if you can figure out which information to ignore, and which information to keep (project).