# A letter telling my great-great-grandfather's death-day

Tags: cipher, story

Yesterday, while I was tidying my attic, I found a letter dedicated to my  great-great-grandfather. (Note that the letter was inside a box which my great-great-grandfather transmitted to my great-grandfather, and so on...) It is supposed to tell him his death-day. I actually know he got murdered, and I also know the exact date when it happened. Now I just want to know if this letter is actually accurate, but I can't decrypt/solve it. Can someone please help me? This is what it says (except the part about how he will be killed):

... 
(5.3-912-83-19-24) + (2.3-12-931-453-1) = mm

(119.9-12-32-183-873) + (300-200-193-930-39.2) = dd

(4.2-342-12-123-847) + (293-1-2-93-8.7) + (59-21-329-12-23-987) + (4.2-181-192-712-9995) = yyyy

Have fun decrypting it. Meanwhile I will wait. You should start learning how to make SOS-signs, because no-one will hear you.

P.S: Don't even think of solving it the "regular" way, like you've learned in school, you silly!

Comment: I upvoted this since it's a nice first post, but it's also very easy. Morse code is one of the first things people will look for in a cryptograms puzzle (along with Baconian cipher, turning letters into numbers, and a few other simple tricks), even without the SOS-clue; and using actual dots and dashes just makes it even more obvious. Have a look at [this question](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/4642/5373) for comparison. There are a lot of bright people here, so you don't have to give *too* many clues! I look forward to seeing more of your puzzles :-)

Comment: Also, the "..." at the start of the month line put me off a bit at first!

Comment: rand al'thor's comment will be one of the first things I look for!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It was on

> 19 November 1901

because (short answer)

> Morse code

or because (long answer)

> Ignore the numbers in the puzzle; they're just a red herring. Concentrate instead on the dots and dashes between the numbers. We get:
> mm = (.----)(.----) = 11
> dd = (.----)(----.) = 19
> yyyy = (.----)(----.)(-----)(.----) = 1901.

Comment: Wow, that was quick! That's the right date!

Comment: @LuxxMiner Gotta be quick here, because people are too good!

Comment: Gave a lot of hints, too, such as `transmitted`, `SOS`... Great nonetheless!

Comment: @Josh Yeah, this is my first post and I was really unsure how many hints I should give :P I'll try to do better next time.

Comment: @LuxxMiner, I think you did very well. Just because it was solved quickly by a bunch of really smart puzzle nerds (no offence, @randal'thor), doesn't make it a bad puzzle. It's a great puzzle, and many great puzzles are solved quickly on this site. Keep up the good work!