# Suicide. Or is it?

Tags: steganography

Death of this man was not expected at all. He was receiving threats, that was publicly known. But still, the crime scene looked like he killed himself, there is no visible third party involved. Victim's colleague came to collect some items needed to work. He also took one of his to-do lists. At least it looked like that. The same day the colleague went to the police station to tell policemen it surely wasn't suicide. What did he read from this list?

> To do. List.
>
> @
>
> 29.01 -write things -cry over my life
>
> -dunno what here -coffe -lunch break
>
> 30.01. -dunno yet
>
> Anything. -Sleep. A lot.
>
> -There is no reason for this list. Obviously.
>
> @
>
> -The sentence above is a lie.
>
> Really.
>
> Although. This. All. Might look not-usual
>
> I'm dead serious now.
>
> .-. I will leave that funny face here
>
> @
>
> -.- Oh look, another one
>
> I remember old days. Young ones.
>
> I used to learn one thing. Alphabet - Morse. Enjoyed a lot.
>
> I had to mention that. -You see. Now.
>
> @
>
> d(--)b
>
> -Funny.-NOT!-XD
>
> I. Wanna. Die.
>
> Bored.
>
> .-If you can't see yet..
>
> But in the end. It's waste. -Trees die for this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

He read this:

> iwouldneverkillmyself

Explanation:

> Some lines represent a morse code, just ignore all characters except `.` and `-`. Then add all those together (line break = space) into one string, decode it and you get that message.

Comment: That was too easy. Will keep that in mind :P

Comment: @Xirate Yep. Funny enough, [my first question on Puzzling](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/18783/a-letter-telling-my-great-great-grandfathers-death-day) was very similar to this puzzle (maybe even easier). So already having made such a puzzle, it probably gave me a little bit of an advantage in terms of time needing to solve this, as I immediately recognized the pattern :P

Comment: Well, I had to give two hints at my first puzzle, got 3k views there :D