# Decode the message enciphered in these symbols: ↗↑↙↓↘←↑↙↘↘↗↓↗←↙↓↖

Tags: cipher, symbols

↗↑↙↓↘←↑↙↘↘↗↓↗←↙↓↖

The first character of the plaintext is 'P'. The final character of the plaintext is 'E'.

Hint 1;

> The second word of the plaintext is DISPUTE.

Hint 2:

> NW = 'end of message'. It's an end-of-file marker.

---

Details (not part of the puzzle):

- **"↗↑↙↓↘←↑↙↘↘↗↓↗←↙↓↖" is the cyphertext. What is the plaintext?**
- The answer is a clue to [The Security to the Party [12] (now with party soundtrack!)](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/4057/the-security-to-the-party-12-now-with-party-soundtrack)
- This type of puzzle is called a [Cryptogram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptogram). The Google search "[How to solve a cryptogram](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?q=%22how%20to%20solve%20a%20cryptogram%22)" leads to all kinds of useful resources, hints and tips.
- The answer is a pair of <s>dictionary</s> words in the English language. The puzzle is *not* case-sensitive. The plaintext does not contain any slang or acronyms, it does not contain any proper nouns (names), it does not contain roman numerals, it does not contain punctuation or spaces.
- For anyone who's having trouble with fonts, and for accessibility: the cyphertext is a series of Unicode arrows pointing in different directions. The sequence is: NE N SW S SE W N SW SE SE NE S NE W SW S NW
- Chat about this puzzle is here: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18676/pick-up-sticks I'll be popping in and out. Feel free to ask any questions there or in comments.
- On some screens it looks like some of the arrows are in bold and some aren't. That is not the intention, it's just the way the fonts look. If you use the list of compass points above then you are at no disadvantage.

---

Update: Argh! I was so busy doing the cipher that I didn't notice the spelling mistake in the plaintext. Well done to nexolute for solving anyway! Future readers beware that the first word of the puzzle is (unintentionally) *not* a dictionary word, because it has a spelling mistake in it. Are my cheeks red!

Comment: is it some kind of octal, hex, binary, morse etc special code again? (yes or no)

Comment: @user2324360 [That's classified. I could tell you, but then I'd have to kill you](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VuE_jqYNi3c) - sorry!

Comment: There is a space between the sixth and the seventh arrow. Should you point this fact in your last bullet point?

Comment: @Victor, there's not meant to be any spaces. If there is one then I'll take it out. thanks for spotting it!

Comment: The answer is "fat hen" - obviously these sticks have already been picked up and laid straight.

Comment: "Pick up sticks" is not intended as a clue, by the way. The arrows just look like sticks.

Comment: @user2324360: but if you want to use automated deciphering tools to exclude some of the simpler or more obvious ciphers (without spending a whole lot of time doing tedious calculations) then that's just fine with me. Use any and all tools and reference materials available to you.

Comment: I have tried nearly ever possible way of translating these arrows to a phone number pad and using those letters, but I've got nothing

Comment: Nice idea though! I might do that one next. :P

Comment: That party is going to ruin my we! :P

Comment: Converting the arrows to hex: `2197 2191 2199 2193 2198 2190 2191 2199 2198 2198 2197 2193 2197 2190 2199 2193 2196`. Droping the `21` and making the rest back as text: **a[c]bZ[cbba]aZc]`**

Comment: @Victor converting hex to dec and dropping (8#) gives `c]_?\] ??c_c\ _b` where ? = error. I've also managed to map to telephone keypad `32789427993834781` no luck

Comment: Is this the trajectory of a fly flying?

Comment: Chat is now open: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18676/pick-up-sticks

Comment: That one escaleted quicky..

Comment: Puzzle updated with Massive Clue.

Comment: I' going with "phantom menace" but no idea how to get there.

Comment: I thought maybe we could follow the trace on the grid of stackexchanges starting from puzzling, but puzzling is at the corner, so there is the issue of looparound.

Comment: @nexolute: interesting idea.

Comment: @Raystafarian: **very** interesting idea!

Comment: Added 2 hints to make it easier.

Comment: Almost 2 years and you guys believed the accepted answer... It's nothing else but [Ryu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ryu_(Street_Fighter))'s hidden move

Comment: @Alex You got me! :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Going in clockwise, ignoring NW, we get the following...

```
N  : AHOV
NE : BIPW
E  : CJQX
SE : DKRY
S  : ELSZ
SW : FMT
W  : GNU
```

And let NW be the EOF character. Now this is where I'm bad with, how can we construct the final solution from these?

Using [regular expression dictionary](http://www.visca.com/regexdict/), I didn't manage to find anything, so I reduce to search with less characters and get use a little guess and check to get **PATERNATY DISPUTE** (should it be patern**i**ty dispute?). Not so sure if this is right?

Comment: you probably just need to see what english words can be made... we now know the last word Is 7 letters long (DISPUTE). so the first word is 9 letters long.

Comment: I edited the answer with my guess of word.

Comment: Correct! On the same theme as http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/4057/  (I'll check it for that possible spelling mistake later, but either way you've got the right answer). Well done!