# Pairs of numbers

Tags: mathematics, number-sequence

You wake up in a cell after a party. You just remember the beginning of the night: you talked to your friends, you drank some alcohol, and then you blacked out.
You stand up and look around you: you are in a small empty room with no window and a door locked with a numeric keypad. 
You approach the keypad and notice a piece of paper:

> You'd better not try to steal my [spaghetti recipe](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/3981/the-security-to-the-party) again!
> I'll let you out if you can solve this puzzle: 
>   `{22,11}`
>   `{49,83}`
>   `{76,56}`
>   `{157,344}`
>   are all acceptable numbers, but
>   `{11,22}`
>   `{72,47}`
>   `{31,70}`
>   `{512,114}`
>   aren't.
>   If you find the key, you can live. (And if you fail, my pet elephant will make sure you wish you *weren't* alive...).

### Question:

What is the key to the puzzle?

### Hint :

> The key is 2-char long

(Note: This isn't a lateral-thinking question, so there's no need for ridiculous answers like "I punch through the wall".)

Comment: I edited it to fix the grammar and spelling. Wasn't sure what you meant by the "key to the puzzle" (I'm guessing the pattern has some number that stands out), and I assumed a "digicode" was a keypad with numbers on it.

Comment: @Deusovi: Great clean up. I was itching to clean it up too, but saw that it was too much work, so I gave up.

Comment: So just to confirm, the key is a single number input on the keypad?

Comment: So is I FALCONPUNCH through a wall still valid?

Comment: @Geobits exactly

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd do some quick addition and type

> **42**

because each number on the left

> turns into **4** if you repeatedly add digits until you get a single digit (49 -> 4+9=13 -> 1+3=4)

and each on the right

> results in **2** (83 -> 8+3=11 -> 1+1=2)

In the invalid pairs, at least one of them is wrong.

Also, you know, it's *the* answer, assuming you know the question.

Comment: Well play, well play :)

Comment: For all that may need a hint to the answer :)
[42](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrases_from_The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy#Answer_to_the_Ultimate_Question_of_Life.2C_the_Universe.2C_and_Everything_.2842.29)

Comment: That's a pretty blatant *hint* :P

Comment: This makes me sad, I was adding digits and I was like of so the left needs to sum to more than the right. But that didn't hold. AAND I just shoulda paid some attention to the actual sums... (and then repeated). but gj.

Comment: @Goinghamateur To be fair, I should credit qwertylpc somehow. His deleted answer led me to the idea. I just don't know how to appropriately credit deleted answers, since many users can't see it. Well, besides this roundabout way, I guess.

Comment: @Geobits When I find I'm in that situation, I go to their profile, find a couple of their good posts and give them a +1 :).